# Remove duplicates when converting multiple rows into CSV using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, rows

I am creating a view where I need to pull all the rows of one column and convert into CSV format.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + CAST(s.marketConfigId AS varchar(MAX)) 
               FROM [Metric].[MetricGoalDefMarket] s 
               WHERE [metricGoalDefId]=21 
               ORDER BY s.marketConfigId 
               FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS marketConfigID
```

Using above query can create a CSV format but it is also displaying duplicates. When you run the above query it is displaying the output as

```
**marketConfigID**
751,751,742,751,751,784,1850,737
```

How can I remove duplicates?

PS: As I am creating a view, I don't want to use functions as I see using dbo.DistinctList from [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/15/sql-server-remove-duplicate-entry-from-comma-delimited-string-udf/) can remove duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `distinct` would work :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(s.marketConfigId AS varchar(MAX)) 
                  FROM [Metric].[MetricGoalDefMarket] s 
                  WHERE [metricGoalDefId]=21 
                  ORDER BY s.marketConfigId 
                  FOR XML PATH('')
                  ), 2,200000) AS marketConfigID
```

You don't need to use `substring()` you can use `stuff()` instead :

```
SELECT STUFF ( (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(s.marketConfigId AS varchar(MAX)) 
                FROM [Metric].[MetricGoalDefMarket] s 
                WHERE [metricGoalDefId]=21 
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, ''
             ) AS marketConfigID
```

Comment: I already tried that. It gives me an error showing "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." Not sure where I could use, as I already used ORDER BY in the query

Comment: Thank for your answer. 2nd query works but how can I put ORDER BY in there. It throws me an error if I put ORDER BY after where clause

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DISTINCT?

Edit: Apologies think I misread your query. I think you want to fetch the marketConfigIds using a sub-select query (applying DISTINCT), rather than at the outer level like I did below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + CAST(s.marketConfigId AS varchar(MAX)) 
               FROM [Metric].[MetricGoalDefMarket] s 
               WHERE [metricGoalDefId]=21 
               ORDER BY s.marketConfigId 
               FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS marketConfigID
```

Comment: Shouldn't that DISTINCT go inside the subquery being XMLPath'd?